# Como afecta el javascript para abrir un dialog en el rendimiento del sitio - astro

Tags: javascript, html

Estuve desarrollando un modal que no dependa de javascript para integrarlo en Astro.
HTML tiene modales nativos con la etiqueta `<dialog>`, y aunque para cerrarlo no requiere javascript, para abrirlo sí, nótese el `onclick='window.dialog.showModal()'` en la imagen.

¿Cómo interactúa este js con astro?
¿El hecho de que no requiera de la carga de un archivo js no afecta el rendimiento del sitio?

```
<button onclick='window.dialog.showModal()' id="open">Open Modal</button>

<dialog id=`dialog`>
<form method="dialog">
  <nav>
    <p class="selected">Home</p>
    <p>Collection</p>
    <p>About</p>
    <p>Contact</p>
  </nav>
  <button id="close">Close Modal</button>
</form>
</dialog>
```

[Implementación de dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ds3Wm.png)

Comment: Hola nahuepera. Dicha [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) forma parte del navegador, es decir, esta disponible en todo momento sin importar si la vas a usar o no. ¿Como afecta esto en el rendimiento del sitio? Por el contrario, diría que si no la usas y cargas algún framework/toolkit para crear modales, entonces ahí si probablemente pueda verse afectado el rendimiento.